# WinForms: не открывается редактор форм

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, c++-cli, visual-studio-2017

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Куда-то пропали иконки по которым можно открыть конструктор форм. Иногда они просто не появляются вообще и я не могу открыть визуальный редактор.  На картинке показано 3 формы, но только одна открывается. 
Как исправить?

Вот Что помогло. Я откомпилировал проект, закрыл проект и открыл заново.
Всё заработало 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Откройте в текстовом редакторе файл `.vcxproj` вашего проекта. Найдите там `ItemGroup` с элементами `ClInclude`. Убедитесь в наличии `<FileType>CppForm</FileType>`.

Comment: Такой текст отсуцтвует

Comment: Я добавил текст  .vcxproj в вопрос

Comment: Не тот файл. Вы показали `.vcxproj.filters`. Во всяком случае, у меня так.

Comment: Исправил в вопросе на нужный файл

Comment: <FileType>CppForm</FileType> присутствует